# Q: Non linear & non autonomous ode system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, fluid-dynamics

How could be solved  (either numerically or analytically) the following dynamic system?

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=a(\frac{h+b.v^2}{h+b.v^2+c})$$
$$\frac{dh}{dt}=d-f.t-g.v$$

where: a, b,c,d,f and g are positive scalars. 
Boundary conditions:
$v(0)=v_0$ and $h(0)=0$

This system is an preliminary model for my undergrade engineering thesis project which is about pulsatile flowes. Finally, i suppose that function solution will contain an exponential form.

Regards,

Comment: What you should google for is "boundary problem solver". There is at least one in MATLAB, as far as I remember. Another quite common way is to use any regular good ODE solver and find the boundary problem solution via shooting method (see [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6701/8119c28b1693575a756417465285449cb5e6.pdf), for example). By the way, ts there really an $f \cdot t$ term in the second equation?

Comment: Hi; ty for the reply. I correct myself: this is an IPV not a boundary problem. I took your advice and use matlab but itcould not find an explicit solution. Well i think the only way is to apply RK4

Comment: Hi; ty for the reply. I correct myself: this is an IPV not a boundary problem. I took your advice and use matlab but itcould not find an explicit solution. Well i think the only way is to apply RK4. I expected to find some analytical solution... F refers to a constante value

Comment: My question was mostly concerning explicit dependence of RHS on time $t$. If there is no dependence on time (i.e., RHS depends only on $h$ and $v$), you can apply methods of dynamical systems theory. You can look for equilibria states, check their type and stability, find some bifurcations depending on parameters. This information is always very useful for verifying numerics and improving numerical analysis. But this approach currently can't be applied because of $f \cdot t$ term in the second equation.